# What type of variable can be level-2 variable? Does higher ICC indicate better multilevel model?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis

I am working on a dataset that has 27 countries, and I would like to investigate how does **individual economic status** influences **well-being**.

**Well-being** was measured by WHO-Five well-being Index (WHO-5). It has five statements, rated on 6-point Likert scale. The final score ranges from 0 to 100 (total raw score * 4).

**Economic status** was measured by a 6-point Likert scale, with 1 = *very easily to make ends meet* to 6 = *with great difficulty to make ends meet*).

I first created a null model. And I used **country** (B001) as the second level. However, the ICC is only 0.02.

```
model1 <- lmer(who5 ~ 1 + (1|B001), data = md)
```

```
REML criterion at convergence: 213477.4

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.9970 -0.7180  0.1086  0.8214  2.4216 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 B001     (Intercept)   9.439   3.072  
 Residual             440.560  20.990  
Number of obs: 23908, groups:  B001, 27

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)    53.89       0.61   88.36
```

**My questions are:**

1. Does that (low ICC) means there no need to use multilevel model?
2. Can I use other variables, for example, **age group** (*18-29, 30-50, 50+*) or **employment status** (*employee, self-employed, unemployed, retired, other*) as the second level, instead of using **country**? Or, generally saying, what kind of variables can be higher level in a multilevel model?
3. I have tried setting **employment status** (emp_stat) as second level, and the ICC increases a bit (from 0.02 to 0.06). Does this means **employment status** is more proper than **country** to be put in the second level?

```
model2 <- lmer(who5 ~ 1 + (1|emp_stat), data = md)
```

```
REML criterion at convergence: 211394.6

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.71347 -0.69237  0.07413  0.84064  2.65384 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 emp_stat (Intercept)  28.19    5.309  
 Residual             435.72   20.874  
Number of obs: 23710, groups:  emp_stat, 5

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)   51.899      2.381    21.8
```

4. In psychology, sometimes we consider **life satisfaction** very similar to **well-being**. So, I changed **well-being** to **life satisfaction** (rated on a scale of 1 to 10, labelled as 1 = *very dissatisfied*, 10 = *very satisfied*) and do the same analysis.

The results showed that ICC increases to 0.05, for **country** as second level.

```
model3 <- lmer(C001_01 ~ 1 + (1|B001), data = md)
```

```
REML criterion at convergence: 102908.4

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.3385 -0.5184  0.0889  0.6207  2.0786 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 B001     (Intercept) 0.2265   0.4759  
 Residual             4.2227   2.0549  
Number of obs: 24029, groups:  B001, 27

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)  6.75152    0.09275   72.79
```

And ICC increases to 0.13, for **employment** as second level.

```
model4 <- lmer(C001_01 ~ 1 + (1|emp_stat), data = md)
```

```
REML criterion at convergence: 101553.6

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.92479 -0.47151  0.01997  0.51063  2.44444 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 emp_stat (Intercept) 0.6448   0.803   
 Residual             4.1538   2.038   
Number of obs: 23821, groups:  emp_stat, 5

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)   6.3851     0.3595   17.76
```

I am confusing why ICC changes 'a lot' when I switch **well-being** to **life satisfaction**, is it because of the scale differences (100 vs. 10) between these two variables? Or, it is just because of the data.

**Thank you in advance :)**

*It is my first time to ask question here, if you have any advice to me for my question format or my title (it is really hard for me to name a title), please  let me know.*